# How to perform animation with an image for calender,ios

Tags: ios, image, animation, calendar

Am pretty new to animation for iphone application.I got an issue regarding the animation.What am trying to do is,in my screen,i took one image and i implemented the calender control using the NSCalender control.What my requirement is if i select any one date,the image has to move in the shortest direction.For example,if i have dates as

```
sun mon tue wed thu fri sat
                     1   2
 3   4   5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20  21  22  23 
24  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

if i select the date 29,the image which is placed at the top of the screen must be moved from 1,8,15,22 and then 29.Like wise if i select the date 19,the image has to move from 5,12 and then 19.Like wise the image has to move.How to perform the animation for this type of screen.Please help me or provide any samples.The image has to move according to the nearest date cell position.I made lot of googling but i didnt find the solution.Great answers would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Both your examples were simply moving straight down. What should for example happen if you move from 28 to 11 or from 8 to 18 or from 2 to 11?

Comment: thanks for responding David.Not like that,when i click the date in the calender,then the image has to move regarding to its position where the dat is clicked

Comment: Yes, but how should it move? I guess it shouldn't move diagonally from where it was, or?

Comment: Can you suggest me in what way if the image navigation looks better David

Comment: David can you give advice to me.Iam helpless in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this cool [Animated Calendar](https://github.com/freesuraj/Animated-Calendar) which is a clone of the famous animated calendar used in the app ["Band of the day"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/band-of-the-day/id459664402?mt=8) ?

Probably this is what you are looking for !